# HTML Transitions Aren't Working With Grayfade

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

What I'm trying to do is hover over my picture and then have it gradually fade to gray using the grayfade CSS stuff. It's not working for some reason that I don't know even though I have looked for hours on transitions. Please help me!

This is all of my code (although the code that you'll want to look at is the img and the img:hover in the style tag):

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Basketball Uniforms 1/24/14</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        }

        html { 
            background: url(assets/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        header {
            width: cover;

            padding: 2em;

            background-color: rgba(17, 40, 87, 0.85);

            border-radius: 0 0 2em 2em;
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;

            color: #FFBB00;
        }

        h2 {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;

            color: #FFBB00;
        }

        h3 {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;

            color: #FFBB00;
        }

        table {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;

            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0 2em;
        }

        td {            
            border-style: groove;
            border-width: 2em;
            border-color: rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.95);
            border-radius: 4em;

            padding: 4em;
        }

        .odd {
            background-color: rgba(242, 153, 51, 0.80);
            color: #22499C;
        }

        .even {
            background-color: rgba(51, 112, 242, 0.80);
            color: #FEBB2D;
        }

        img {
            width: 26em;
            height: 20em;

            border-radius: 1em;

            -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s ease;
            -moz-transition: -moz-filter 0.5s ease;
            -ms-transition: -ms-filter 0.5s ease;
            -o-transition: -o-filter 0.5s ease;
            transition: filter 0.5s ease;
        }

        img:hover {
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
            -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
            -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
            -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: url(assets/grayscale.svg);
            filter: gray;
        }

        h4 {
            padding-top: 1em;

            text-align: center;
        }

        h5 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        footer {
            width: cover;

            padding: 2em;

            background-color: rgba(17, 40, 87, 0.85);

            border-radius: 2em 2em 0 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Basketball Uniforms Through the Ages</h1>
        <h2>Leo Alfred&#58; 1/24/2013</h2>
    </header>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="odd">
                <a href="http://uniformcritics.com/basketball/nba/portland-trail-blazers/1970-trail-blazers-debut-road-uniform-vintage-retro-throwback/">
                    <img src="assets/1970.jpg" title="1970&#39;s Basketball" alt="1970&#39;s Basketball">
                </a>

                <h4>Portland Trail Blazers</h4>
                <h5>1970 - 1971 Debut Road Uniform</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="even">
                <a href="http://uniformcritics.com/basketball/nba/golden-state-warriors/1980s-warriors-away-california-uniform-vintage-retro-throwback/">
                    <img src="assets/1980.jpg" title="1980&#39;s Basketball" alt="1980&#39;s Basketball">
                </a>

                <h4>Golden State Warriors</h4>
                <h5>1980 - 1985 Road Uniform</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="odd">
                <a href="http://uniformcritics.com/basketball/nba/milwaukee-bucks/1990s-bucks-road-uniform-throwback/">
                    <img src="assets/1990.jpg" title="1990&#39;s Basketball" alt="1990&#39;s Basketball">
                </a>

                <h4>Milwaukee Bucks</h4>
                <h5>1993 - 2005 Road Uniform</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="even">
                <a href="http://uniformcritics.com/basketball/nba/la-clippers/2000s-clippers-away-uniform-red/">
                    <img src="assets/2000.jpg" title="2000&#39;s Basketball" alt="2000&#39;s Basketball">
                </a>

                <h4>LA Clippers</h4>
                <h5>2000 - 2009 Away Uniform</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="odd">
                <a href="http://www.spartanjerseys.com/michigan-state-basketball-jersey/2010-2011/">
                    <img src="assets/2010.jpg" title="2010&#39;s Basketball" alt="2010&#39;s Basketball">
                </a>

                <h4>Michigan State Spartans</h4>
                <h5>2010-2011 Uniform</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <footer>
        <h2>An LFX Design Website</h2>
        <h3>&#169; 2014 LFX Design</h3>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for helping me with my transition-grayfade problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-order the `transition` properties, it seems like there was some interference. Placing `transition: filter 0.5s ease` first seemed to fix it. I assume this had to do with the fact that it was overwriting the other prefixed-properties.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2sCRN/2/)

```
img {
    transition: filter 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-filter 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-filter 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: -o-filter 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s ease;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(assets/grayscale.svg);
    filter: gray;
}
```

This doesn't occur when using `all`, [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/78L9C/) therefore I assume there was an issue use `-webkit-filter` as a property value. I guess it's a browser support related issue.